# Java can we break a string into 2 strings when a new line accure

Tags: java, android

i am trying to get a number row from camera using android offline text recognition (OCR). I want to get a number from camera,and object detection must stop when a new line comes.

```
@Override
public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {
    final SparseArray<TextBlock> items = detections.getDetectedItems();
    if (items.size() != 0) {
        textView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                    TextBlock item = items.valueAt(i);
                    stringBuilder.append(item.getValue());
                    //stringBuilder.append("\n");
                    intNumber = stringBuilder.toString().trim();
                    //intNumber = intNumber.replaceAll("\\D+","");
                }
                //textView.setText(stringBuilder.toString().trim());
                // intNumber = intNumber.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "" );

                // substring = intNumber.substring(0,18);
                number = intNumber;
                textView.setText(intNumber);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can like following.

Example String:

```
String stringWithNewLine= "one\ntwo";
```

You can convert it into an array with

```
String myArray[] = stringWithNewLine.split("\n"); // myArray =  {"one", "two"};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this `String lines[] = string.split("\\r?\\n");`

It's just simple method then easy to get all split in to array Cheer's

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use String.split() there are many other ways also
[Java split string](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/string/4-ways-to-split-tokenize-strings-in-java/)